# Proving that there are infinitely many composites in an arithmetic progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

The question says

> Consider $S$={$a, a+d, a+2d, ...$} where $a$ and $d$ are positive integers. Show that there are infinitely many composite numbers in $S$

The only argument I could think of was that primes aren't equally spaced. So, the rest of the numbers must be composite numbers, which are infinitely many in number. Is this a legit solution, or is there a more elegant way to prove this?

Would appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not true that the "spacing between primes" increases.

Comment: @AnotherUser It does give me an idea, but my question is about infinitely primes, not consecutive primes

Comment: @lulu Thanks, I made the necessary edits now

Comment: If the sequence contains $k$ consecutive composites for all $k$ then it obviously has infinitely many composites.

Comment: @lulu So is my solution OK?

Comment: You don't provide a solution.  How do you use the fact that "the primes are not equally spaced" to solve the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136331/discussion-between-aarush-mishra-and-lulu).

Comment: I don't think there's a need for a chat...the linked duplicate provides a nice, clear solution.

Comment: A different proof can be obtained by noting that the natural numbers contain arbitrarily long consecutive blocks of composites.  Thus every progression contains some composites.  But that immediately implies that every progression contains infinitely many composites (why?).

Comment: @AdamRubinson Nice

Comment: @lulu Can the 'why' part of your comment be testified by the same argument I gave in the description?

Comment: Again, you don't provide an argument.  Just asserting that the primes aren't equally spaced does not settle the question.  A priori it seems possible that *some* infinite collection of primes are equally spaced, after all.  The point of this exercise is to show that this can not happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addendum added to cover the case of $(a=1)$.

---

There is a much easier answer than the ones provided in the link.

If $a,d$ is not relatively prime, then it is immediately game over.  That is, if $e|a$, and $e|d$, then none of the elements in the sequence can be prime.

So, assume that $a,d$ are relatively prime.  The following argument doesn't really require that assumption.  However, it does provide clarity to the situation.

Consider the terms in the positions $(a+1), (2a+1), (3a+1), \cdots.$

These terms will be $(a + ad), (a + 2ad), (a + 3ad), \cdots.$

Each of these terms will be divisible by $a$, and therefore composite.  Therefore, there will be an infinite number of composite terms.

The linked answer tackles a much tougher problem, and can therefore be regarded as overkill.

---

**Addendum**
Thanks to B. Goddard for finding the flaw in my analysis, re $(a = 1)$.  In that case, the term in position $r$ will be $1 + (r-1)d.$

Take $k \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$

Then the term in position $(d^{2k}+1)$ will be $1 + d^{2k}(d) = 1 + d^{2k+1}.$

Since $(2k+1)$ is odd, the number will be divisible by $(d+1)$.

Therefore, when $a=1$, there will still be an infinite number of composite terms.

Comment: Unless $a=1$, then you need something else.

Comment: @B.Goddard Nice catch.  See my addendum.

Comment: @user2661923 Nice and elegant solution. Thanks!

Comment: I have a simpler argument which covers all cases at once. The second term, $a+d,$ will always be greater than $1.$ Then every $a+d$ steps, we have terms of the form $a+d+k(a+d)d=(a+d)(1+kd)$ for some natural number $k,$ which is guaranteed to be composite.